# my mobile is not showing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, usb-debugging

My mobile is not showing in android studio inside available devices when i connect it with usb cable to run the app in my physical device. I have pdanet+ app in my mobile and I already ON the **developer option and usb debugging**. It's working fine some days before but suddenly its not working.

i am using :
Android Studio 3.6.1
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 27, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: de.mprengemann.intellij.plugin.androidicons

Please help me to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Standard things to try-  unplug the device, reboot the device, kill the adb server on your machine and restart it

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Please follow this step :
step1: remove the USB from the device
step2: restart the android studio
step3: goto SDK manager
step4: goto SDK tools tab
step5: update Android SDK Platform-Tools
step6: now connect the mobile device with a USB
```

Comment: how do you "remove the USB from the device"?

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to your phone's Developer Options:

> Settings > Additional Settings > Developer Options

2. Scroll down to "DEBUGGING" section.
3. Activate "USB debugging" option.
4. **IMPORTANT STEP:**

Within "Developer options", scroll down to the "NETWORKING" section and open "Default USB configuration".

Set it to "USB tethering".

5. If Android Studio is running on your PC, a popup should appear on your phone saying "Enable debugging" or something like that. Enable it and your device should now be detected in android studio.

Comment: I am using oppo a37 and can't find `NETWORKING->USB tethering`

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps for your query:

Step 1:
Make sure your device is enabled for development. If yes, go to Step 2, otherwise, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times which is magic number :-). Now Developer Options is available in the Settings.

Step 2:
Before you plug your device to PC, Go to Settings > Developer Options and select the USB Connection method.

Step 3:
Plug the phone to the PC, you are given options for the USB Connection method, and please select Internet connection. Make sure you have connected to the Internet. By the way, I have changed MTP to PTP, it did not work for me. Therefore, I tried Internet connection mode, then it worked.

Step 4:
Run the app in the Android Studio, it will ask you to authorize the device for development, and select YES!.

Step 5:
Run the application via Android Studio and choose the device, not emulator, and BINGO! Welcome to the Android development board.

Another option is:- There are many reasons why Android Studio doesn't see a mobile phone.

One of them is a problem with the ADB Interface driver. You can check it in your Device Manager:

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to enable the developer mode.
 Here is a link on how to do so:
 https://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/

Then try to restart android studio, if the problem is not fixed. Also, make sure your device is unlocked and that the cable works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. I followed the instructions on the "***Troubleshoot Device Connections"*** located on the Devices dropdown:

1. Make sure your Android phone is connected via USB to your computer
2. Go to your Android phone
3. Go to **Settings > About phone > Software information** on your phone
4. Tap **Build number** seven times
5. **Developer** option is now enabled in your phone
6. Go to **Developer**
7. Turn on or enable **USB debugging**
8. Allow computer access to phone
9. Now click on ***"Troubleshoot Device Connections"***
10. Click Next until you reach ***"Restart ADB Server"***. Click on that and restart

Your device should now show on the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that your device is not showing on Android Studio while you are connected with the data cable close the Android Studio completely and restart it. Your device will connect with it then.